# Create or edit custom configuration section at runtime

Tags: .net, configuration, runtime, configurationsection, custom-configuration

I have a custom configuration section, something like:

```
<fooSection>
    <foo>
      <add bar="cow" />
      <add bar="dog" />
      <add bar="goat" />
    </foo>
</fooSection>
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can add/edit this section in the `app.config` file in a test fixture setup. I don't really know where to start, but an obvious problem is that my `ConfigurationSection` does not expose any setters.

Comment: You should be able to deserialize the XML directly to a `fooSection` object.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do it through the normal code, because, as you mentioned, it only exposes getters. You can change the file however, as it is just another text file. But then the changes will probably not be picked up without restarting the application (in your case your test runner).

So you might want to look at another mechanism for this. For example a small database, an XML file, [application settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), ...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`DeserializeSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.deserializesection.aspx) - just pass it an [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) that points to the configuration.

Comment: I don't follow you. I'm trying to write to the config file. Can you give an example?

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet - Why are you trying to write to the config file in your tests?

Comment: The config file contains scheduling information which needs to be set relative to the current date in order that the test results are consistent.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet - So your code depends on static configuration?

Comment: well, it depends on a config file yes, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Looks like bad design... http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/configuration-settings-are-a-dependency-that-should-be-injected

Comment: I agree completely with that article, and I have unit tests in place already. I am now trying to write a simple end to end/integration test and imho that should include executing the schedule as specified in the config file, since that is part of the specification.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet - OK. My answer was that you should be able to deserialize XML into an instance of your `ConfigurationSection` class and pass that into your code.